# Load Library classes through autoload.php as per request in the codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework for my application, I am loading the some CI libraries through autoload.php. From CI I loaded the following libraries:
'database', 'session', 'smarty', 'doctrine','log'. Also I created many custom libraries which I am loading through autoload.php file.

But it takes around 1.5 MB server memory after loading all the libraries. So I decided to load the libraries only when library is required.

Should I write condition in autoload.php file. Or is there any other better approach for loading library classes conditionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can just load them where you need them. In controller methods, model methods, constructors, wherever. It would make more sense to add them where they will be used rather than try and account for all cases where they may be needed in the autoload file.